# Package can't solving in pub after upgrade flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, package

In my app , I'm using Some packages

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
module:
  androidX: true

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.0
  google_maps_flutter: 1.0.3
  google_map_location_picker: 4.0.0
  mvc_pattern: 6.3.0
  global_configuration: 1.6.0
  http: 0.12.2
  html: 0.14.0+4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+2
  flutter_html: 1.0.2
  flutter_svg: 0.18.1
  location: 3.0.2
  webview_flutter: 0.3.24
  url_launcher: 5.7.7
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.3
  cached_network_image: 2.3.3
  fluttertoast: 4.0.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.3.2
  intl_utils: 1.8.0
  carousel_slider: 2.3.1
  cloud_firestore: 0.14.1+3
  firebase_auth: 0.18.1+2
  firebase_core: 0.5.0+1
```

And now I have some error in my pub

Because google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 depends on intl >=0.16.0 <=0.16.1 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.3 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.

So, because food_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and google_map_location_picker 4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because food_app depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and google_map_location_picker 4.0.0, version solving failed.)

and I'm trying to use **any** for packages and it makes more errors

So , How can I deal with this problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have also got this kinda issue many times. And there is only one solution is to provide range for packages.
**Eg:**

```
  flutter_polyline_points: ">=0.2.4 < 0.3.0"
  google_maps_flutter: ">=0.0.1 < 2.0.1"
```

**Reason:** Here your packages **automatically choose stable package version**.

Make sure to **choose your left limit as lowest as possible version and right limit is latest version**.
You can *check versions in version Section of Doc*.

Comment: when I'm trying your solution I getting this error 
Because google_map_location_picker >=4.1.4 <4.1.7 depends on intl >=0.15.3 <=0.17.0-nullsafety.2 and google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.4 depends on intl_translation >=0.17.9 <=0.17.10, google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.7 requires intl >=0.15.3 <=0.17.0-nullsafety.2 or intl_translation >=0.17.9 <=0.17.10.
And because intl_translation >=0.17.7 depends on intl >=0.15.3 <0.17.0 and every version of flutter_localizations depends on intl 0.17.0, flutter_localizations  is incompatible with google_map_location_picker >=3.3.1 <4.1.7.

Comment: Please share me your pub.ymal file updated code.